# How to run Linq with order by and group by

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have three tables in DB

1. **VoucherQuestionCollection**
2. **Post**
3. **PostComment** (Contains the multiple comments of Post table)

The relation between tables is

```
VoucherQuestionCollection.discussionid = Post.PostId
and Post.PostId = PostComment.PostId
```

VoucherQuestionCollection table have one column named "WonDate" which contains datetime values. What i need is, i need to fetch the data from VoucherQuestionCollection table based on following conditions:-

1. VoucherQuestionsCollection's WonDate that should be the least date (say the one which going to expire first)
2. PostComment's comment count should also be the least count. (that is the posts with lowest comment)

So how do i build the query in Linq to produce the desired output by considering above conditions?

This is what i did so far, but stuck with how to proceed further.

```
 var voucherQuestionTotalCollection = (from voucherQuestionCollection in this.GetDbSet<Jimble.Model.VoucherQuestionCollection>()
                                                  join posts in this.GetDbSet<Jimble.Model.Post>() on voucherQuestionCollection.DiscussionId equals posts.PostId
                                                  join comm in this.GetDbSet<Jimble.Model.PostComment>() on posts.PostId equals comm.PostId into gj
                                                  from sub in gj.GroupBy(c => c.PostId).Select(g => new { Available = g.Count() }).DefaultIfEmpty()
                                                  where voucherQuestionCollection.UserId != userId && voucherQuestionCollection.VoucherWonDate > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7)
                                                  orderby voucherQuestionCollection.VoucherWonDate descending
                                                  select new { Id = voucherQuestionCollection .Id,
                                                               VoucherWonDate = voucherQuestionCollection.VoucherWonDate,
                                                               DiscussionId = voucherQuestionCollection.DiscussionId,
                                                               TotCommentCount = sub.Available
                                                  }).OrderBy(c=>c.TotCommentCount);
```

**Sample table**

```
VoucherQuestionCollection                    Post                    PostComment
Id  DiscussionId   WonDate                   Id     PostText         Id   PostId   CommentText

1   1              2014-11-21 17:13:00.113   1      FirstPost        1    1        CommentText1
2   2              2014-11-22 17:13:00.113   2      SecondPost       2    1        CommentText2
3   3              2014-11-23 17:13:00.113   3      ThridPost        3    2        CommentText3
4   4              2014-11-24 17:13:00.113   4      FourthPost       4    2        CommentText4
                                                                     5    2        CommentText5
                                                                     6    3        CommentText6
```

This is the output i need
If the table status is like i shown above, the expected output is VoucherCollectionTable's 3rd entry since it has only one count in comment table. 
If the PostComment table have equal comments i need to get the entry of 1 from VoucherCollectionTable since the least date is 2014-11-21 17:13:00.113

**NOTE**: The VoucherQuestionCollection will have multiple entries i need to fetch only six records based on this above condition.

Having trouble to understand my explanation above, simply this is the SQl Query

```
Select * from VoucherQuestionCollections a 
inner join Posts b on a.DiscussionId = b.PostId
Left join (Select PostComments.PostId,COUNT(PostComments.PostId) as tot from PostComments Group    by PostComments.PostId)c on b.PostId = c.PostId
order by a.VoucherWonDate,c.tot
```

How to write this same in Linq

Comment: Can you add any sample input & output you are expecting? Its difficult to understand your DB table structure.

Comment: @RahulSingh is my question still confusing? Please check my edited question.

Comment: @JeffMercado Do you have any solution to this?

Comment: @RahulSingh if you think my question requires research effort or if it is clear please up vote it, so others will notify on it.

Answer (score 1):

From the appearance of your database structure you don't need to group by. Just order by `VoucherWonDate` descending and then by the number of `PostComments` for the associated `Post`.

Try something like:

```
var voucherQuestionTotalCollection = 
this.GetDbSet<Model.VoucherQuestionCollection>()
.Where(p => p.UserId != userId )
.OrderByDescending(p => p.VoucherWonDate)
.ThenBy(p => p.Post.SelectMany(q => q.PostComments).Count());
```

I have included the where clause from your query which was not mentioned in the question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How does my joins work with count along with your suggestions in my question? I have three tables, one table (PostComment) is left joined, i need its count, How can get it. I thought in order to get that count we need to use Group by clause in my linq. Can you explain it?

Comment: @NithinPaul No, the count can also be achieved by a subquery inlined in the SELECT clause, which is probably going to be generated from this LINQ statement (if this is Entity Framework). The message is: if possible, use navigation properties, not `join`, in LINQ. The only thing is, is should be `p.Post.SelectMany(p1 => p1.PostComments).Count()`.